# shiboken typesystem not inheriting classes

Tags: python, c++, qt, binding

I have two shiboken libraries to export Qt bindings to Python.
My classes in Lib2 that subclass Lib1 do not inherit any methods from the binding including any QWidget/QObject methods.

I have loaded the typesystem:

```
<load-typesystem name="source/plugin/typesystem_lib1.pyside.xml" generate="no" />
```

And the resulting binding is usable, but it is missing the inherited methods.
The code is namespaced if that makes a difference.

Has anyone had any luck with something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
It looks like shiboken actually adds these based on the import order in the shiboken-header file (global.h)
So you need to ensure all dependencies of that header are included before your include that header, and all includes must be in the shiboken-header, you cannot include a file that includes other files as they won't be respected.
Also shiboken will not use a full path, only the header name, so I have created an auto sym-link during build that creates a symlink to my headers and names them path_to_data.h to be unique.
/Edit

So it turns out that the reason that this fails is because my two class files have the same name, and shiboken gets confused when including the information.

Shiboken loads the headers from the shiboken-header, but it strips them to just the file name instead of keeping the full path, which meant we get:

```
#include "/path/to/data.h"
#include "data.h"
```

And if data.h is somewhere on the include path it will find the class with the same name in it.

I would consider this a bug but hopefully this helps anyone else coming across this issue.